# Django-registration ImportError: No module named signals

Tags: django-registration

I am trying to write a signal listener for django-registration and I am getting the import error: no module named signals. But I could import registration.

Here is my code

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from registration.signals import user_registered

def user_registered_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    """signal intercept for user_login"""
    user = kwargs['user']
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
    login(user)

user_registered.connect(user_registered_handler)
```

-- Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I sent it too soon. Uninstalled registration(0.7) that I installed using easy_install and reinstalled django-registration-0.8-alpha-1. Is alpha the final version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a specific path to version 0.8. I noticed that using easy install and pip installed 0.7 which does not have signals.py.

Using pip:

```
$ pip install -Iv https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/downloads/django-registration-0.8-alpha-1.tar.gz
```